# using static_cast with boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I want to transform a vector of type T to a vectorof type K.
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
transform(vec.rbegin(),vec.rend(),vecNew.begin(),boost::bind(static_cast<K>(),_1));
```

I get the error: "expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Use the boost cast functor `ll_static_cast<K>()`

Comment: You might say that it should be used because static_cast<T> is an operator, like sizeof, and not a function.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the static cast unless there is no implicit conversion from T to K. If the conversion constructor is not explicit, or if you a T::operator K(), you can just do:

```
transform(vec.rbegin(),vec.rend(),vecNew.begin());
```

Note that this reverses the order of the elements as well.