# Functor version of static_cast in std::bind()

Tags: c++, bind, functor, static-cast

I try to implement a functor version of `static_cast` for use in `std::bind()`.

I am aware of Boost `ll_static_cast<K>()` (see [using static_cast with boost::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430152)), but I am not using Boost right now.

There is a code example in [Why do several of the standard operators not have standard functors?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6336025) but it won't compile on GCC 4.2.1:

```
template <typename Target>
struct StaticCast
{
    template <typename Source>
    Target operator()(Source&& source) const
    {
        return static_cast<Target>(source);
    }
}
```

I managed to get something to compile, but I am not sure it's correct:

```
template <class Target>
struct StaticCast : public std::unary_function<void, Target> {
    template <class Source>
    Target operator()(Source& src) const {
        return static_cast<Target>(src);
    }
};
```

Can someone tell me if this version is correct, and if this is the case, why I need `std::unary_function` which is not used in the previous code example?

Usage:

```
std::vector<BaseObject*> vec;  // BaseObject* are known to be of type 
    // DerivedObject* of course, please don't ask me how or why...

std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    std::bind(&DerivedObject::doStuff,
        std::bind(StaticCast<DerivedObject*>(), std::placeholders::_1),
    "with some string"));
```

Comment: If you're using C++11, but not use lambdas? `std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](BaseObject* obj) { static_cast<DerivedObject*>(obj)->doStuff(); }`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with GCC 4.2.1 for the moment, which does not support them (I removed `tr1::` in the code for simplicity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the lack of perfect forwarding in C++03, you'll have to make due with overloads:

```
template<class Target>
struct StaticCast
{
    typedef Target result_type;

    template<class Source>
    Target operator ()(Source& src) const
    {
        return static_cast<Target>(src);
    }

    template<class Source>
    Target operator ()(Source const& src) const
    {
        return static_cast<Target>(src);
    }
};
```

Note that I'm explicitly making a `typedef` for `result_type` rather than inheriting from `std::unary_function<>`. The reason is that the first template parameter to `std::unary_function<>` is supposed to be `operator()`'s argument type, but because our `operator()` is a template we can't know this in advance, so it's disingenuous to supply one in the first place (especially `void`, which would imply that `operator()` is nullary, when in fact it is unary).

---

Also, for completeness' sake, here is the correct C++11 version of the functor:

```
template<class Target>
struct StaticCast
{
    template<class Source>
    Target operator ()(Source&& source) const
    {
        return static_cast<Target>(std::forward<Source>(source));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason the first one doesn't work is probably because you are using rvalue references on a compiler that doesn't support C++11.

The reason you need `std::unary_function` is to enable `std::result_of` for your class which `std::bind` uses to deduce the result type, since there is no decltype in C++98.

If you look at `std::unary_function` you will see that it defines the type `result_type` from the template arguments you pass, which is in turned used by `std::result_of` or `std::bind` directly.

Comment: In fact, even without rvalue references it doesn't work, so I guess the reason is the deduction of the result type. If I understand correctly, type can be automatically deduced in C++11 and not in C++98?

Comment: @OlivierB: That's why I wrote **one** reason. Yes, types cannot be automatically deduced in C++98, while it can in C++11 using `decltype`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally your code is bad:

First, you may have troubles with temporary objects and r-values while requesting non-const reference for them

for example

```
float f = StaticCast<float>()(4);
```

won't even compile.

Then, you *make a copy* of object while casting. It may be do not that you want.

Source example *free* of that disadvantages due to `move` semantics

Comment: Well, I have to agree... To what I understand, there is not a perfect way of doing it with GCC 4.2.1.